# Window resizing based on label size doesn't consider title bar in pyQT5

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I'm coding a simple image viewer and would like for the window to resize based on the image that I open.

The window I'm using is a QMainWindow and has a toolbar. The only widget I have is a QLabel which is set as the central widget. When I open the image I use `self.resize(self.label.sizeHint())`, but the window size doesn't take into account the size of the title bar and the toolbar, so for example if I open a 400x400 image the window will be of the correct width, but a little bit too short.

What would be the correct way to calculate the correct window size so that it resizes correctly on every platform? (Windows, macOS, Linux)

EDIT: the minimal code is:

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as w
import PyQt5.QtGui as g
import PyQt5.QtCore as c
import sys

class ImageViewerWindow(w.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.loadedImagePaths = []
        self.imageIndex = 0
        self.scrollArea = w.QScrollArea()
        self.label = w.QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.label.setAlignment(c.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(1,1)
        # Actions
        self.openAction = w.QAction("Open...", self)
        self.openAction.setShortcut(g.QKeySequence.Open)
        self.openAction.triggered.connect(self.openMenuDialog)
        # Toolbar elements
        toolbar = w.QToolBar("Top toolbar")
        toolbar.setMovable(False)
        toolbar.setContextMenuPolicy(c.Qt.PreventContextMenu)
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)
        # Status bar elements
        self.setStatusBar(w.QStatusBar(self))
        # Add actions to toolbar and menu
        toolbar.addAction(self.openAction)

    def showImageAtIndex(self, index):
        image = g.QPixmap(self.loadedImagePaths[index])
        self.label.setPixmap(image)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.label)
        self.imageIndex = index
        self.angle = 0
        self.label.adjustSize()
        self.resize(self.label.sizeHint())

    def openMenuDialog(self, firstStart = False):
        self.loadedImagePaths, _ = w.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(parent=self, caption="Select one or more JPEG files to open:", filter="JPEG Image(*.jpg *.jpeg)")
        if self.loadedImagePaths:
            if firstStart:
                self.show()
            self.imageIndex = 0
            self.showImageAtIndex(self.imageIndex)
        elif firstStart:
            sys.exit()

a = w.QApplication([])
ivw = ImageViewerWindow()
ivw.openMenuDialog(firstStart = True)
a.exec()
```

If you try and open an image and then resize the window you will notice that some of the image is covered by the title bar and the status bar.

Comment: Please show your code rather than describing it.

Comment: I added the link to the code, it's too long to paste here.

Comment: @FedericoChiesa questions should be self-contained and not rely on external resources that can make the question invalid or impossible to understand (which is true especially for repositories, since their contents are always going to change), please provide a [mre] *in* your question.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that using [`setWidgetResizable()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop):

> the scroll area will automatically resize the widget in order to avoid scroll bars where they can be avoided

So you have to remove that line, *or* use `setFixedSize()` on the label using the image size.

Then, calling `adjustSize()` on the label is not enough, as you actually need to call `adjustSize()` against the top level window: this is because calling `resize()` with the image size won't consider all other widgets in the window (in your case, the toolbar and status bar).

Unfortunately, that won't be enough, as QScrollArea caches the size hint of the widget, and calling again `setWidget()` with the same widget is useless.

The easiest solution is to use a subclass of QScrollArea and reimplement the `sizeHint()`.

Finally, the alignment only has effect on the label *contents*, but when the widget is added to a container the alignment has to be set *for* the widget.

```
class ScrollAreaAdjust(w.QScrollArea):
    def sizeHint(self):
        if not self.widget():
            return super().sizeHint()
        frame = self.frameWidth() * 2
        return self.widget().sizeHint() + c.QSize(frame, frame)


class ImageViewerWindow(w.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.loadedImagePaths = []
        self.imageIndex = 0
        self.scrollArea = ScrollAreaAdjust()
        self.label = w.QLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.label)
        self.scrollArea.setAlignment(c.Qt.AlignCenter)
        # ...

    def showImageAtIndex(self, index):
        image = g.QPixmap(self.loadedImagePaths[index])
        self.label.setPixmap(image)
        self.label.setFixedSize(image.size())
        self.imageIndex = index
        self.angle = 0
        self.scrollArea.updateGeometry()
        self.adjustSize()
```

Note that the size hint of a top level window will only be respected until the size doesn't exceed 2/3 of the screen size. This means that if the image will force the window to a slightly bigger size, at least one scroll bar will be shown, even if it's not strictly necessary.

There is no obvious nor universal solution for that, and you need to find your own way. For instance, you can check if the scroll bars are visible *after* adjusting the size and eventually compare the size of the image *and* that of the scroll area's viewport, then if one of the image dimensions is just smaller by the size of the opposite scroll bar, force a resizing of the top level window by that scroll bar size.